# Mysql update if one of fields is a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My DB has table ip(address, count) and I want to update the 'count' value if address is found in DB, else add a new record. I do this:

```
INSERT INTO ip(address,count)
VALUES('0.0.0.1', 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+VALUES(count);
```

But as a result a have this table:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | address | count |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | 0.0.0.1 | 3     |
|  2 | 0.0.0.1 | 3     |
|  3 | 0.0.0.1 | 3     |
+----+---------+-------+

  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Why doesn't it sum 'count' , but makes a new record always ? How do I change primary key ?

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for above

Comment: Are you sure you have created address as Primary key?

Comment: is it good to make 'address' as primary key ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, that would depend on the requirements and the purpose of your table. But, unless and until you make that PK/Unique key, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` would not work, as you are expecting. Since, this feature tracks duplicate values coming on the key attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your table using following query

```
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
    `id` INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `count` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `address` (`address`)
)
```

Then use following query to insert

```
INSERT INTO ip(address,`count`) VALUES('0.0.0.1', 3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
```

In this case if table already contain that ip, then count will be incremented by one.

Please note that column `address`  should be either `UNIQUE index` or `PRIMARY KEY`, otherwise this wont work. In my create table query i set `address` as unique.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually created the unique key on the address column? If you haven't then the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause will never run and so rows will keep being created.

Could you update your question to include the schema for the table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark `ADDRESS` as UNIQUE key for this to work.

Quoting from documentation

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed

Comment: how do I change the primary key ?